# value get changed after insert into mysql custom variable

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I was working on mysql custom function. I created new function Code giving below as :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `getNewLogicPassFailStatus`(Id varchar(20),subject1 varchar(520)) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    select MAX(writenscore) into @writtenscore from exam.marks WHERE Id =ID and subject = subject1;

    return @writtenscore;
END
```

No syntax error found, butit's giving result without applying where clause.
excepted output :  11 showing : 48

But select query working fine without function as below

```
select MAX(writenscore) as max from exam.marks WHERE Id = 1 and subject = 'maths';
```

I even check whether function getting correct parameter or not.

Comment: You need to declare `@writtenscore` variable before using in the Select statemet

Comment: i try still its not working

Comment: should it be WHERE Id = Id ? not ID because you define Id varchar(20)